# PHP HTTP 500 during same domain redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, session-state

I create a clients manager for an association and during an update it stopped to work online. In my local machine it does function without problems. Updates are about some second page's buttons actions. The website is composed of two pages: the first one is a simple login page with quickly md5 check. The second page has 3 sections for add, view and download clients's data. During updates I didn't modified the login page but now, after the files upload, I continuosly receive HTTP 500 Internal server error after the login submit. I tried to comment the session_start load and check to open the second page directly.. nothing.. I'm not able to understand the domain log, can you help me?
(I changed http to xxxx because I couldn't post more than 2 links)

```
93.xxx.xx.xxx [subdomain.domain].com - [22/May/2015:16:27:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

93.xxx.xx.xxx [subdomain.domain].com - [22/May/2015:16:27:54 +0200] "GET /STF/MOD/styUI.css HTTP/1.1" 200 443 "xxxx://[subdomain.domain].com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

93.xxx.xx.xxx [subdomain.domain].com - [22/May/2015:16:27:54 +0200] "GET /STF/MOD/scpJQuery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 29532 "xxxx://[subdomain.domain].com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

93.xxx.xx.xxx [subdomain.domain].com - [22/May/2015:16:28:01 +0200] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 650 "xxxx://[subdomain.domain].com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

93.xxx.xx.xxx [subdomain.domain].com - [22/May/2015:16:28:02 +0200] "GET /main.php HTTP/1.1" 500 26 "xxxx://[subdomain.domain].com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Here the redirect function where $urlIN is main.php and $delayIN is 0:

```
function fnRedirectTo($urlIN, $delayIN) {//sleep($delayIN);header('Location: '.$urlIN);}
```

EDIT:

I 've also found this error log:

```
[client x.xx.xxx.xx] [host **SUBDOMAIN**.**DOMAIN**.com] (13)Permission denied: /homez.2018/**USER**/mercatino/DATA/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://**SUBDOMAIN**.**DOMAIN**.com/main.php
```

SOLUTION:

Finally I came across my trouble.. There was an error in a function, I wrote:

```
if (strpos(!empty($fileTMP, $nameTMP)))
```

instead:

```
if (strpos($fileTMP, $nameTMP) !== false)
```

I don't know why the server killed the page considering the above portion of code is triggered by a submit button. Anyway.. it's solved! Yeap

Comment: Hey Giacomo, you should add your solution as an answer below, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Finally I came across my trouble.. There was an error in a function, I wrote:

```
if (strpos(!empty($fileTMP, $nameTMP)))
```

instead:

```
if (strpos($fileTMP, $nameTMP) !== false)
```

I don't know why the server killed the page considering the above portion of code is triggered by a submit button. Anyway.. it's solved! Yeap